# Basic threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

OK the code is pretty basic. Since I'm using multiple threads, and I want shared variables between them, I'm using a global.

Why does the code in ThreadClass sometimes not execute when I hit "C"? I know it's a concurrency problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've reading up on semaphores and locking lately, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it at the moment.
Any suggestions are welcome.

```
import threading
buff_list = []

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    global buff_list
    def run(self):
        while (True):
            if ("C" == raw_input()):
                buff_list.append("C")
                print buff_list

class ThreadClass2(threading.Thread):
    global buff_list
    def run(self):
        while(True):
            if ("B" == raw_input() and len(buff_list) > 0):
                buff_list.pop()
                print buff_list

a = ThreadClass()
b = ThreadClass2()

a.start()
b.start()
```

Comment: Two side notes: In Python you don't need parentheses around `while` and `if` conditions, and shouldn't use them. Also, you never need to check `len(buff_list) > 0`; just check `buff_list`, because any sequence is truthy iff it's not empty. The problem with adding unnecessary parentheses, `len` checks, etc. is that most Python programmers will assume you were trying to do something for which they _are_ necessary, and waste time and mental effort trying to guess what your intention was.

Comment: Also, you usually don't want to call `list.pop()` and not store the result anywhere. But I assume you know that, and were just doing it this way because it's a toy example (the value can't be anything but `"C"`, and you have nothing useful to do with it anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two synchronization problems here.

Let's deal with the easier one first, the fact that you're sharing a global `buff_list` that the two threads fight over. There's nothing stopping one thread from trying to `append` at the same time the other thread `pop`s, which is illegal. And, even if you get lucky and that doesn't happen, the `pop` could come *before* the `append`.

---

The simplest way to solve this is to use a [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), which is automatically-synchronizing:

```
buff_list = Queue.Queue()
```

Then just use `put` instead of `append`, and `get` instead of `pop`.

---

However, if you want to learn how to this stuff yourself, there are two possible ways to go.

First, you can use a [`Lock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects). (You can also use an `RLock`, but let's forget that for now.) This makes sure that only one thread is accessing `buff_list` at a time.

```
buff_lock = threading.Lock()
buff_list = []
```

Now, whenever you append or pop, just grab the lock:

```
with buff_lock:
    buff_list.append("C")

with buff_lock:
    val = buff_list.pop()
```

---

But this won't make sure the popping code waits until there's something to pop. If you want to do that, use a [`Condition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects):

```
buff_cond = threading.Condition()
```

Now:

```
with buff_cond:
    buff_list.append("C")
    buff_cond.notify()

with buff_cond:
    while not buff_list:
        buff_cond.wait()
    value = buff_list.pop()
```

---

The second problem is that you're implicitly sharing `sys.stdin`, because both threads are calling `raw_input`. Unless you have some way to synchronize things so that each thread knows when it's supposed to get the next input (and that may be hard to even describe, and you can't turn it into code if you can't describe it), that can't possibly work—every time you type `C` there's a 50/50 chance that the wrong thread will get it.

So, as kirelagin suggests, you need to make exactly one thread responsible for the I/O. The easiest way to do this is again to use a `Queue`, and have one thread `put` any inputs it doesn't use, and the other thread can `get` from the queue.

Comment: The simplest way to solve this is to avoid using threads where you don't need theads…

Comment: @kirelagin: Well, yes, in the same way that the simplest way to solve any coding problem is to not write any code…

Comment: well @kirelagin I'm trying to make a bigger threading program later on. So to do so, I wanted to first understand how it works in a really basic program.

Comment: Taking the original code and rewriting it to use locks per @abamert's comments was a great exercise for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well you never know instance of which class got your input. If you hit “C” and that was `ThreadClass2` reading your input, it will just do nothing since `"B" == raw_input()` will be `False`.

Exactly one thread should be responsible for I/O.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is said in the previous replies, i would like to add that **threading** module also supports more primitive mechanisms implemented also in all other languages, such as the [Semaphore Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects).

*This is one of the oldest synchronization primitives in the history of computer science, invented by the early Dutch computer scientist Edsger W. Dijkstra (he used P() and V() instead of acquire() and release()).*

The best way to learn threading in deep is starting from scratch, i think.

Comment: I think it's a lot easier to start with `Queue`, then figure out how to write `Queue` yourself on top of `Lock` and `Condition`, then figure out how to write `Lock` and `Condition` on top of `Semaphore` and `Event` (writing `Condition` that way is hard, and the result will not be very efficient), rather than starting with the lowest-level primitives and trying to figure out what you could conceivably build out of them.

Comment: *Easy* is often in contradiction with *best*. You will not have `Queue` or `Event` at kernel level for example. Use them at the beginning force  *lazy* programming. If you want to learn in depth the concept of thread synchronization and let it works in every context and language, then the road is a bit harder but it brings greater results. This is what I meant.
However, there may be different ways depending on the purposes. I only suggested a possibility :)

Comment: Yes, it's important to know how to write a condition or a synchronized queue or a lock-free list out of nothing but semaphores, events, and compare-and-exchange. But until you know what they're used for, you can't do that. Instead, you'll build useless things at the wrong level of abstraction that work 99.99% of the time, and spend 99.99% of _your_ time debugging code that doesn't even make sense. It took the industry a couple of decades to figure out the useful abstractions, and if you try to work bottom-up and discover the abstractions yourself, it will take you just as long.